# How and where i can apply await in my async method

Tags: c#

I am new to async and await in c#. I am trying to read some 300 text files where I am using List which is calling a function "ReadFiles". I made this function Async but I don't know how to modify my code now to use await. where should I use the await keyword so that it can run my program without throwing an error. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code :

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var file in folderFiles)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         ReadFile(file.FullName, folderPath, folder.Name, week);
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
DateTime stoptime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan totaltime = stoptime.Subtract(starttime);
label6.Text = Convert.ToString(totaltime);
textBox1.Text = folderPath;
DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Read the files successfully.", "Important message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

public async void ReadFile(string file, string folderPath, string folderName, string week)
{
    int LineCount = 0;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            sr.ReadLine();
        }

        string oline;
        while ((oline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            LineCount = ++LineCount;
            string[] eachLine = oline.Split(';');

            string date = eachLine[30].Substring(1).Substring(0, 10);

            DateTime dt;

            bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

            if (!valid)
            {
                Filecount = ++Filecount;
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + "Files_with_wrong_date_format_" + folderName + ".txt", true);
                sw.WriteLine(fileName + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Line number :" + " " + LineCount);
                sw.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                int calculatedWeek = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.Localized).GetWeekOfYear(Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Saturday);

                if (calculatedWeek == Convert.ToInt32(week))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Filecount = ++Filecount;
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "/" + "Files_with_dates_mismatching_the_respective_week_" + folderName + ".txt", true);
                    sw.WriteLine(fileName + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Line number :" + " " + LineCount);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }       
        }
    }
    //return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make couple of changes.

First change the void to Task

```
public async Task ReadFile(string file, string folderPath, string folderName, string week)
```

Second change sw.WriteLine to await sw.WriteLineAsync

```
await sw.WriteLineAsync(fileName + "  " + "--" + "  " + "Line number :" + " " + LineCount);
```

Finally, call the method as bellow.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var file in folderFiles)
        {
            var task = ReadFile(file.FullName, folderPath, folder.Name, week);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Also, you need to synchronize the Filecount variable as:

```
lock(new object())
{
     Filecount++;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. But in my opinion it is better and well-performing if you just read the files inside  async Task ReadFile and does not calculate anything and return the status of the file then collect all 300 status and do the rest. This way, you don't need the lock or any other synchronizations.

Comment: I did it in the same way...and the result is awesome. Now it is taking around 5.30 min to do the iterations on around 17 GB of data. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change

```
public async void ReadFile(string file, string folderPath, string folderName, string week)<br/>
```

and make it return a Task preferably the value that you want at the end of method.
Since async void used together means fire and forget. Which means it will start the execution wont wait for it to complete but execute the rest of statements while continuing execution in background. So you will end up receiving `Read the files successfully.` message before you even finish having read file.

Comment: Thanks. Earlier my "ReadFile" function was bool , but as someone suggested me to use async and await as my program was taking so much of time in execution of 300 text files. Can you please help me by telling how can I use async and await in my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not directly what you ask, but you should not confuse async/await with multi-threading. So if what you're after is multiple threads handling different files at the "same time", you should not use async/await.

If this is not what you're after, but what you actually want is async/await, you need to use async methods to actually gain anything from it. So when you call WriteLine/ReadLine on the StreamReader/StreamWriter, you should actually use the WriteLineAsync method and ReadLine async method. Otherwise there's no gain.